# How does one add advertizing in a python android app

Tags: android, python, mobile, ads

I was wondering if there was any way to add advertising in an android app written in python. The only examples I could find involve making apps with java, but I want to integrate them into a python android app. I am using Kivy to make my app, not sure if you can do it with Kivy, or if you can set it up on the website. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using something like this:

[first](http://www.appnext.com/?ref=gg_%2Badvertise%20%2Bon%20%2Bandroid%20%2Bapps_b&gclid=CO65sd2WhL0CFcU-MgodVmYABw)
[second](https://www.offercastmobile.com/developers.html?gclid=CLLolt6WhL0CFYZAMgodz1sAGw)

Good luck on your app!

Comment: Thanks!, I would upvote, but I'm new to sorceforge, and it says I need 15 reputation to do that -_-

Comment: Your welcome. I'm trying to get 15 reputation too so I can upvote.